# find single or multiple \n at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to capture the values of a tab separated list:

```
1   11  11111111
2   22  2222
3   33  33333333
```

It is pretty straightforward except that the last line could have a trailing `\n` which gives me some errors when I loop through the lines in other areas of my script. If it has this trailing `\n`, I would like to get rid of it. I could do this:

```
var res = myStr.substr(-1);
if (/\n/.test(res)){
    return myStr.substr(0, myStr.length - 1)
}
```

But of course this will fail to truncate a string with multiple trailing `\n`. I suppose I could loop through with the substring approach until the last character isn't an `\n`, however I wonder if there's a more elegant regex approach.

```
/^\s*[\r\n]/gm.test(myStr)
```

for some reason only returns true when there is more than one `\n` at the end of the string, and returns false when there is exactly one `\n`.

I thought to use the jquery `$.trim()` method, but it will truncate the last line if it is only tabs. I can't do this because I still want to keep account of the presence of that line even if it is empty.

Not that the loop is a totally unsupportable idea, but is there a way to solve this with a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
var result = yourString.replace(/\n+$/,"");
```

In regex basics,

- `+` is a quantifier for "1 or more occurrences of previous character"
- `$` is "the end position of string" anchor.

Comment: Wow. Bravo! Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of it then try

```
myTest = $.trim(myText)
```

Note: It will remove empty spaces also

else try testing `/\n+$/.test(myText)`